# Closest match of X,Y,Z coordinates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking to match a table of X,Y,Z points between two sets of data.

The difference between the two sets is that the sign of the Y value is flipped.

For example in this screenshot I set "target" as the values I'm looking for, where the Y value is the negative of the value in column D.
[image: sample data table + desired targets1]

I am using a combination of index and match, but this finds exact matches not the closest match:

```
=INDEX($C$7:$C$1048576; MATCH(1; (I120=$D$7:$D$1048576) * (J120=$E$7:$E$1048576) * (K120=$F$7:$F$1048576); 0))
```

In a data set of a few hundred points, about one hundred won't be exact matches.
I'd like a formula to find the closest match to the target points.

Comment: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/distance-relationship-between-two-points-d_1854.html shows how to calculate the distance between two 3D points.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/distance-relationship-between-two-points-d_1854.html shows how to calculate the distance between two 3D points.

For example to identify the closest match between the point in A-C and the list in F-H:

[image]

EDIT: dealing with the "flipped" Y values -

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tim!  This was part of the answer.  The difference in "pure" distances was producing too much error.  I`m providing the answer below

Comment: See my edit above on how to deal with the sign difference on the Y values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who saw and provided help for this.

After chatting with a friend about this, we found that the solution was to calculate a "weighted" distance using the following modified formula for distance:

d = sqrt(x^2 + (2y)^2 + (2z)^2)

Then using the differences of these modified differences, we were able to match the points against their opposites, within reasonable error (we used an error bound of 0.005 for the entire data set and this matched every single point).